# Tridion ComponentLink not resolving

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We have a single Componentlink out of many such ComponentLinks on a page that is not resolving correctly. There are tons of similar Componentlinks on the page and they also resolve correctly except this one. We have tried publishing the component referred to by the link , the page that the component is on, the page where this link does not appear, separately with no errors but this one link does not resolve to an anchor tag of the form

Here is what we see in Template Builder and the rendered page

Partial Output of Template Builder

```
<p class="break">
    <a href="/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/Preview/Preview.aspx#id=tcm:111-8211" >
        Learn more <span class="arrow-right"> </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Partial Rendered Page output

```
<p class="break">
    <tridion:ComponentLink pageURI="tcm:111-3943-64" componentURI="tcm:111-8211" 
        templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" addAnchor="false" 
        linkText="Learn more &lt;span class=&#34;arrow-right&#34;&gt; &lt;/span&gt;" 
        linkAttributes="" textOnFail="true"/>
</p>
```

Comment: He link to your partial output doesn't seem to work.  Can you please paste directly into the question?  Also, please provide the rendered source that the browser sees.

Comment: Also, do you use any TBBs that do custom component link resolving?

Comment: If you find SO helpful for solving your Tridion questions - Please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 using your SO account - The SDL Tridion community really needs all the support we can get

Comment: Nickoli, We do not have any TBBs that do custom component link resolving

Answer (score 2):

Your rendered component link in the page looks pretty normal. Try doing a *Where Used* on the component with URI `tcm:111-8211`. Check if it is used on a page other than `tcm:111-3943-64`. If it is on some other pages, check the priority of the Component Templates. At least one of them must be set to a priority other than *Never Link*.

Comment: Also worth checking the link log information in cd_core.log if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a failure to only one component in a page, that should behave like an anchor? Then why do I see addAnchor="false" in your output, Can you make it true in the file and try?

Also Can you make sure you followed the simple steps mentioned here ?
http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/component-link-samples.html